# Javascript devtool VM instance find initiator

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to localize a memory leak.

Up to now I can see that when I navigate quickly back and forth between 2 features in my app there are new workers or VM instances created in the momory tab. (If I go slow it is not happening)

Any idea how can I find who is the initiator of this threads?

[image]

I can also see a lot of threads in the **Threads** view (when I go clicking mad), but nothing happens if I click on them, I cannot find who is the creator of those.

[image]

Note: This is a big app. I tried recording the timeline, but I'm just lost there... too many things. Thats why I would like to identify this first.

Thanks.

Comment: Those "threads" are Worker instances so set a breakpoint in the code that creates them.

Comment: It would be great if I knew who creates them :) I would not ask the question... They may be instantiated by a lib I have no clue. That's what I'm trying to find if possible from dev tools

Comment: I would run global search (Ctrl-Shift-F) for `new\s+\w*?Worker` in regex mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm At the end I have used the same technique, fortunately there were not many workers so I could track them. Thanks, if you wish you can add an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I ave used the technique proposed by @wOxxOm (thanks)

i.e. I globally searched (in Chrome dev tool `Ctrl + Shift + F`) for the text `new Worker` and fortunately there was no many workers in the application code, so I could identify who is creating them, by break pointing in all of location where the text was present.